# Limitation over the cpu parallelization in training of a stacking model

Tags: azure, scikit-learn, xgboost, ensemble-learning

In Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio, I use `Standard_F32s_v2` to train a `StackingClassifier` which is based on `RandomForestClassifier` and `XGBClassifier`.

```
estimators = [
    ('RF', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=3000, max_depth=10, n_jobs=-1)),
    ('LR', LogisticRegression(max_iter=4000)),
    ('XGB', XGBClassifier(n_estimators=17, min_child_weight=22, max_depth=9, eta=0.16))
]

clfStack = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_jobs=-1)
```

The training is performed via `cross_val_predict`

```
pStack[component] = cross_val_predict(
        estimator=clfStack, 
        method='predict_proba',
        X=X 
        y=y, 
        cv=group_kfold.split(X, y, z), 
        n_jobs=-1, 
        verbose=3)[:, 1]
```

Unfortunately, the multiprocessing is bounded for 20 CPUs only. Any way to increase the number of the used CPUs?

Training set is 10000 samples x 250 features

Could it be related to the cross-validation k=20?

[image]